# WPF Toolbox in shared projects

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am using shared projects in MSVS 2022. In these projects we have xaml files. When I open such a XAML with the MSVS WPF designer, the XAML is displayed correctly, but I don't have WPF controls and other controls in the project toolbox? What's wrong?

If I copy the xaml into the main project and take it out of the shared project, the whole thing works. But I want to customize the WPF-design in the shared project. I can also change code files there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you give me a minimal achievable example? I don't understand your procedure. Preferably using github for my quick deployment.